# Converting two's complement hex values to binary using PHP

Tags: i2c, php

I'm reading x-axis accelerometer data from an IC via the I2C bus using I2C-Tools' ( specifically `i2cget` ) in Linux.  Here is the code that is reading these values:

```
$OUT_X_L_A = shell_exec( 'i2cget -y 1 0x19 0x28' ) ... returns 0x20
$OUT_X_H_A = shell_exec( 'i2cget -y 1 0x19 0x29' ) ... returns 0xfc
```

The [documentation for this accelerometer](http://www.pololu.com/file/download/LSM303DLHC.pdf?file_id=0J564) states that these values ( 0x20 and 0xfc ) are expressed in 2's compliment.  This accelerometer has 16 bit resolution.

From another application I'm running that is reading this data in C, I believe that these values, when converted to a decimal value, should equal ~65,475 ( essentially no acceleration as the device is sitting on my desk ).  Some other documentation I've found suggests that $OUT_X_L_A is the Least Significant Register and $OUT_X_H_A is the Most Significant Register.

I've done some research, but am generally unfamiliar with Two's Complement and LSB and MSB.  How do I calculate this decimal value from the two hex values returned by the device using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is a means of representing negative numbers in binary, using one bit to indicate positive or negative.  We called these *signed* numbers since they have a sign, + or -.  *Unsigned* numbers are always positive. So where a 16-bit "unsigned" number has the range 0 to 65535 (2^16), a 16-bit "signed" number in two's complement has the range -32768 to 32767 (+/- 2^15).

What you have is two 8-bit registers, making up the top and bottom half of a 16-bit value.

> From another application I'm running that is reading this data in C, I believe that these values, when converted to a decimal value, should equal ~65,475

The C application is obviously then reporting the value as *unsigned*, since 65,475 is outside the range of a 16-bit signed value.  For people more versed in dynamically typed languages like PHP than strongly typed ones like C, *type conversion* is harder to grasp, but note that if you convert 65,536 to a signed 16-bit two's complement number, you get -1. So, if that number from the application were properly expressed, it would actually be relatively close to zero (-992 to be exact).

> The documentation for this accelerometer states that these values ( 0x20 and 0xfc ) are expressed in 2's compliment.

This is a misinterpretation.  What's meant is that when you put the two halves together, you'll have a 16-bit number in two's complement.  To do that, you need to shift the MSB up by 8 bits and add it to the LSB:

```
$msb = 0xfc;
$lsb = 0x20;
$n = ($msb << 8) + $lsb;
```

If you print this, you'll get 64544, because that what fc20 is in decimal.  However, that's **not** the two's complement value -- that's the unsigned value.
I am not really a php user (so forgive me if any of my syntax is clumsy), but from what I know of it, the way to convert would be via pack/unpack:

```
$a = unpack(
    's', 
    pack('v', $n)
);
```

If you print `$a[1]`, you now get the correct answer (-992).  I'll leave it to you to read the php manual on pack() and unpack() but to explain briefly: `pack('v' $n)` takes the value in $n and returns a "binary string" version, presuming that $n is an unsigned number.  We have to do this because, while php uses signed integers, they are more than 16-bits long; using pack like this truncates it properly (so the binary string is 16 characters).  `unpack('s')` takes that string, treats it as a 16-bit *signed* value, and puts it into a php integer (the only thing in the return array).